# How to set single row view as default in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a master interactive grid feeding a detail interactive grid on the side that always has exactly one row.
I want this detail interactive grid to be displayed in single row format.
I have looked at all the attributes and googled it for hours but I am stumped.

Any ideas?

Single row view looks like this: http://prntscr.com/moi8ra

Comment: Can you define or provide an image what a single row format would look like? An interactive grid with one row of data is what I would imagine, but not sure how you would like it to appear.

Comment: Why don't you have a classic region feeding your detail IG?

Comment: I like using interactive grids, but even if I didnt, the detail IG would still be an IG so I dont see what difference it would make.
And I also added what single row view looks like, its basically a form.

Comment: What do you think about create a link in your IG that refresh an item with the PK of your detail table. And then use that item to refresh the fields of a form (not a detail IG).

Comment: Alternatively, maybe that plugin helps in some way. https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:2133036973826::::P710_PLG_ID:MHO.IG_SET_ITEMS

Comment: I guess I could just screw off with the interactive grid and do an interactive report with a linked form, its not what I wanted, but at least it works :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make an interactive grid show up in single row view by default (like the selection "Single row view" in the row actions menu), put the following code into the attributes / settings of your PAGE (NOT your interactive grid), section `JavaScript` > `Execute when page loads`

```
var ig$ = apex.region("StaticID").widget();
ig$.interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("single-row-view");
```

Replace `StaticID` with the StaticID of your interactive grid.

I know that this is old, but it was on top of my google search results, without the question being answered correctly.
I had the same question , and I have been searching the web for hours on how to accomplish this. And it's so easy, once you found it. ;-)

Kind Regards,
Nadine

Comment: Well I managed to solve my problem a different way, without using Single row view, but it is always useful to share data like this in case anyone needs it again. So I thank you for your contribution